# Only the event listeners at the top of the JS file work, why?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

The code below opens and closes two simple menus - Team Message Box and Navigation.

Right now only the "Team message box" will work, but if I put "slide out navigation" first then it starts working and the team message box stops working.  Why is this?

```
//team message box, open and close
let teamMessageDeliveryOpenBtn = document.getElementById("teamMessageDeliveryOpenBtn"),
    teamMessageDeliveryCloseBtn = document.getElementById("teamMessageDeliveryCloseBtn"),
    teamMessageDeliveryBox = document.getElementById("teamMessageDeliveryBox");

teamMessageDeliveryOpenBtn.addEventListener("click", openTeamMessageBox, false);
teamMessageDeliveryCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", closeTeamMessageBox, false);

function openTeamMessageBox() {
    "use strict";
        teamMessageDeliveryBox.style.height = "50rem";
        teamMessageDeliveryBox.style.visibility = "visible";
}
function closeTeamMessageBox() {
    "use strict";
        teamMessageDeliveryBox.style.height = "0";
        teamMessageDeliveryBox.style.visibility = "hidden";
}


//slide out navigation
let navButton = document.getElementById("navButton"),
    navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");

navButton.addEventListener("click", navOpenClose, false);

function navOpenClose() {
    "use strict";
    if (navBar.style.height === "20rem") {
        navBar.style.height = "0";
    } else {
         navBar.style.height = "20rem";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use your debugger to see what is really going on, but I see that you are not using classes, which always gives problems.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback, perhaps I will try putting this into classes.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to my problem.  The issue was not every ID in the js file was on every html page.  So depending on which page I was looking at js would throw an Uncaught TypeError because it couldn't find one of the element ids.

Comment: Create `function id_(id) {return ((document.getElementById(id)) ? document.getElementById(id) : false);}` Then use `if (id_('teamMessageDeliveryOpenBtn')) {}`.

Comment: I think this would work, however I ended up adding classes to the body tag on each page and then just checking for the existence of the class using this:  if (document.body.classList.contains('main_navigation_available')) { code I want to execute here }

Comment: The `body` *element*, it is almost always inappropriate to use the term tag. Also the `body` element should look like this always: `<body>`: no attributes. I've created an entire web platform from scratch using no third party frameworks or libraries and it's at worst 2.5X faster and upwards of 24X faster. Go check the DOM on the site linked in my profile and have a look at the code and the documentation. Why learn from scratch or bad tutorial sites when there is better? :-)